# How to convert XML to OCI-Lob Object?

Tags: php, xml, oracle, clob, oracle-call-interface

I have a XML as below -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<step number="9">
  <s_name>test</s_name>
  <b_sel>123456</b_sel>
  <b_ind>7</b_ind>
</step>
```

I want this to be converted to OCI-Lob object as below -

```
OCI-Lob Object
(
    [descriptor] => Resource id #130
)
```

I have looked for almost all the threads related to OCI-Lob in PHP but didn't get the information which I am looking for.

Hope you understand my question. Any suggestions on this would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get OCI-Lob Object We do need Oracle Select Query in addition we can pass XMLAttributes/Elements with getClobVal() or any function. But We can't parse XML and convert it to OCI-Lob Object as it always interact with the Oracle Database/Server.

[OCI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29589826/how-to-use-xml-to-create-oci-lob-object)