# Convert XML to Object in PHP and again convert that Object to XML?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, domdocument

Lets say I have a XML as below -

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<step number="9">
  <s_name>test</s_name>
  <b_sel>12345</b_sel>
  <b_ind>7</b_ind>
</step>';
```

I want this to be converted to object, but when I perform below steps, it gives me stdclass object as below [I am assigning it to $stepInformation variable] -

```
$xml = json_decode(json_encode((array) simplexml_load_string($xml)), 1);

$stepInformation = stdClass Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [number] => 9
        )

    [s_name] => test
    [b_sel] => 12345
    [b_ind] => 7
)
```

So when I am parsing this stdclass object in a php function

```
function convertStepInformationToArray($stepInformation)
{
     $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $stepInfo = "{$stepInformation->s_name}{$stepInformation->b_sel}{$stepInformation->b_ind}";    
$dom->loadXML("<document>" . $stepInfo . "</document>");
    $domx = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $entries = $domx->evaluate("//step");
    return $entries;
}
```

The output I am getting is

```
DOMNodeList Object
(
    [length] => 0
)
```

I want `[length] => 1` to proceed with my project. I know the problem is with the `<step number="9">` which is coming as below after converting it to object.

```
stdClass Object
    (
        [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [number] => 9
            )
```

**NOTE**- I have even tried with below steps but no luck:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

$stepInformation = SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [number] => 9
            )

        [s_name] => test
        [b_sel] => 12345
        [b_ind] => 7
)
```

Could you guys please give me some pointers on this, how can I get the output as below ? Any alternative approach would be Ok, as long as I am getting the exact output -

```
   DOMNodeList Object
    (
        [length] => 1
    )
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: do you have any particular reason why you would have the need to use `json_encode/decode` when you can already parse values from the `SimpleXML` object?

Comment: Just updated my question. I have even used SImpleXML, but no luck.

Comment: record in $stepInformation  doesn't give stdClass Object output.. you have written array in `(array) simplexml_load_string($xml)` and you are fetching `$stepInformation->s_name` like an object.

Comment: To convert a SimpleXML object to a DOM one, just use [`dom_import_simplexml`](http://php.net/dom_import_simplexml) - it doesn't even have to re-process the XML, because they both use the same representation internally. (There's a `simplexml_import_dom` to go back the other way, too.)

Comment: @hakre They are different questions altogether. http://stackoverflow.com/q/29818820/367456 is for Getting OCI-Lob Object from XML content. And this question is for converting the XML to stdclass/SimpleXML object.

Comment: Sure, and you asked those two absolutely independent to each other. If your question changes, you have to reflect it in the question, not just post a new one. This includes if you make a question more broad to reach a larger audience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually don't need to load the `SimpleXML` object into that `json_encode/decode`.

You can use that object already and parse whatever values you needed. Having to `encode/decode` as an array and to have to access values and then converting it into `SimpleXML` is too much.

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<step number="9">
  <s_name>test</s_name>
  <b_sel>12345</b_sel>
  <b_ind>7</b_ind>
</step>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

$step = $xml->xpath('//step');

echo $step[0]->attributes()->number; // 9

echo $xml->s_name, '<br/>', $xml->s_name, '<br/>', $xml->b_ind;
```

[Sample Output](http://missingbrackets.com/codepad/editor/MRgS9i)

With `DOMDocument` alone:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

echo $xpath->evaluate('string(//step/@number)');
```

Just keep it simple:

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<step number="9">
    <s_name>test</s_name>
    <b_sel>12345</b_sel>
    <b_ind>7</b_ind>
</step>';

function convertStepInformationToArray($stepInformation) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadXML($stepInformation);
    $domx = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $entries = $domx->evaluate("//step");
    return $entries;
}

print_r(convertStepInformationToArray($xml));
```

Comment: I need the Object to be passed in the function convertStepInformationToArray($stepInformation) where $stepInformation holds the XML object.

Comment: @CloudFreezer if you're really required to return a `DOMNodelist`, then load the xml string into the `DOMDocument` directly instead

Comment: Buddy, Can't thank you enough. You just ROCK. You saved me big time :)

Comment: @Ghost: OP is a self-duplicator.

Comment: @Ghost Can you pls help me to solve Object to xml. My code : https://justpaste.it/64gie

Comment: @Gem hi, you can create your own question, it would garner more attention and better answers

Comment: My account not working properly I can't able to Post. Can you pls help me.